# Problema com Struct em C

Tags: c, algoritmo, struct

Nesse código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Usando o struct(Estruturas)
  struct cadastro {
    char nome[50];
    int idade;
    char rua[50];
    int numero;
    };
 int main()
 {
     printf("Digite suas informacaoes:\n");
     struct cadastro c;

     printf("Digite seu nome:\n");
     //Le do teclado uma string e armazena no campo nome
     gets(c.nome);

     printf("Digite sua idade:\n");
     //Le do teclado um valor inteiro e armazena no campo idade
     scanf("%d", &c.idade);

     printf("Digite o nome da sua  rua:\n");
     //Le do teclado uma string e armazena no campo rua
     gets(c.rua);

     printf("Digite o numero da rua:\n");
     //Le do teclado um valor inteiro e armazena no campo numero
     scanf("%d", &c.numero);

     system("cls");

     printf("Nome: %s\n", c.nome);
     printf("Idade: %d\n", c.idade);
     printf("Rua: %s\n", c.rua);
     printf("Numero: %d\n", c.numero);

     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

Não consigo digitar o nome da Rua com o scanf, pula direto para a leitura do int numero.
No printf ele não informa o rua, não consigo resolver.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Retirei o system("cls")(limpar a tela) para mostrar.

Comment: Pode trocar o gets(c.rua) por fgets(c.rua, 50, stdin) e testar?

Comment: Pois é, olhando seu código, não tenho certeza se o problema está no gets(c.rua) ou no scanf acima. Você pode testar seu código sem as linhas em que pergunta-se a idade? Testa com a pergunta do nome e depois a pergunta da rua, um seguido do outro. Ve o que acontece.

Comment: Pois é cara, o problema não tá no gets(), mas sim no scanf("%d", &c.idade). Como se o "enter" que é dado nesse momento da execução afetasse a execução do gets(). Testa isso aqui, por favor: 

no lugar do scanf("%d", &c.idade), coloque as duas linhas: 
scanf("%d", &c.idade);
getc(stdin);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então, algumas coisas você precisa corrigir, e o programa que irei postar funciona. Se você quer ler espaços precisa ajustar, fiz rápido agora e irei te deixar uns links pra corrigir esse "probleminha" no C.

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct cadastro {
    char  nome[50];
    char rua[50];
    int idade;
    int numero;
};

struct cadastro c;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("Digite suas informacaoes:\n");

    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &c.nome);

    printf("Digite sua idade: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.idade);

    printf("Digite o nome da sua rua: ");
    scanf("%s", &c.rua);

    printf("Digite o numero da rua: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.numero);

    printf("\nNome: %s\n", c.nome);
    printf("Idade: %d\n", c.idade);
    printf("Rua: %s\n", c.rua);
    printf("Numero: %d\n", c.numero);

    return 0;
}
```

http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/C-C++/Ler-nomes-com-espaco
  http://blog.lucaspolo.com.br/2010/07/lendo-string-com-espacos-na-funcao.html

Comment: não, o gets não deve ser usado e o programa tinha coisas que nao precisava/nao deveriam. Esta mais enxuto, só catar ali o codigo que se ajusta melhor pra leitura da string no scanf e ficará pronto.

Answer (score 3):

Na verdade o problema maior está - além do gets - em quer "capturar" o `\n`. Com o exemplo Yonathan é resolvido, mas não se pode pegar nomes com espaço. Para capturar nomes com espaços e não ter esse problema coloque antes de cada formtado de captura do scanf um espaço. Ex: `scanf(" %[^\n]", c.rua);` <- espaço antes do %

Principalmente porque a captura de numéros com inteiros também "pega" o o inteiro e deixa o `\n` sobrando. Código para ler com strings sem problemas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

    struct cadastro {
    char nome[50];
    char rua[50];
    int idade;
    int numero;
};

int main(void) {

    struct cadastro c;

    printf("Digite suas informacaoes:\n");

    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", c.nome);

    printf("Digite sua idade: ");
    scanf(" %d", &c.idade);

    printf("Digite o nome da sua rua: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", c.rua);

    printf("Digite o numero da rua: ");
    scanf(" %d", &c.numero);

    printf("\nNome: %s\n", c.nome);
    printf("Idade: %d\n", c.idade);
    printf("Rua: %s\n", c.rua);
    printf("Numero: %d\n", c.numero);

    return 0;
}
```

Bastaria um espaço no terceiro `scanf`, mas coloque em todos por precaução. Caso precise utilize a função

```
void clearStdin(void){  

    int c;

    while(( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && ( c != EOF ));
}
```

para remover qualquer fluxo que ainda esteja acumulado na entrada, fazendo com que seja descartado. Basta por a função depois de qualquer saída, principalmente as de nomes com tamanho pré-determinado.

Exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct cadastro {
    char nome[50];
    char rua[50];
    int idade;
    int numero;
};

void clearStdin(void){  

    int c;

    while(( c = getchar() ) != '\n' && ( c != EOF ));
}

int main(void) {

    struct cadastro c;

    printf("Digite suas informacaoes:\n");

    printf("Digite seu nome: ");
    scanf("%49[^\n]", c.nome);
    clearStdin();

    printf("Digite sua idade: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.idade);

    printf("Digite o nome da sua rua: ");
    scanf(" %49[^\n]", c.rua);
    clearStdin();

    printf("Digite o numero da rua: ");
    scanf("%d", &c.numero);

    printf("\nNome: %s\n", c.nome);
    printf("Idade: %d\n", c.idade);
    printf("Rua: %s\n", c.rua);
    printf("Numero: %d\n", c.numero);

    return 0;
 }
```

Pois caso o usuário digite algo maior que 49 caracteres os demais serão descartados.